# The domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains and the code for login is

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am trying to connect my app to facebook and I'm getting this error each time.

The error is:

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains

And the code for login is:

```
<?php
include('src/facebook.php');
$config=array(
'appId'=>'887139291301329',
'secret'=>'97b958ddcc451e07d0f40aaad0ad74b2'
);

$facebook=new Facebook($config);
$user_id=$facebook->getUser();
echo $user_id;
if($user_id)
{
 echo "welcome user";
} 
else
{
  echo "u r not logged in please click here to login";
  $login_url=$facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo "<a href='$login_url'>Log In</a>";

}
?>
```

If somebody can help it will be appreciated please help me

Comment: Did you configure the Basic settings on developers.facebook.com/apps?

Comment: sir what do you mean by basic settings and i want one more quest what should in place of app domain....what url should i have to use....?

Comment: You should add a Platform. Ignore app domain completely

Comment: then what should come in add platform..what would you prefer to me..

Comment: You add the platform you want